# Django: How to authenticate a user who have some special permission

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

[here is the permission that i assign to user you can see the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z24mW.png) I am new to Django. I am working on a project where I want to login a manager. Manager is not a admin or superuser here but a manager have some permission which is given by admin from back end. I want that if a user/manager have a specific permission then it will render a different page. 
I have done it for admin but i have no idea how can i do it for a user who have some permission. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my views.py for authentication of user and admin.

```
def login(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    # print(request.POST)
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        # return redirect('index')

        if user.is_superuser:
            return redirect('manager')

        elif user.has_perm('app.edit_task'):
            return redirect ('master')

        else:
            return redirect ('index')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect('login')    
else: 
    return render(request, 'vadash/sign-in.html')


here is my model.py

class manager(models.Model):
 class Meta:
    permissions = [
        ("edit_task", "can edit the task"),
    ]
```

how can i authenticate a user/ manager who have some special permission.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What would need to be different?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman   i want that if a manager will login then it will render a different. SO how can i authenticate a manager     NOTE: Manager has some permissions given by admin..

Comment: What does "render a different" mean?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman   like render a different page for example : if a manager login then he will redirect to /manager page.

Comment: But you're already doing that for admins. What's stopping you doing it for managers?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman  in my project there is a admin who have all the permissions and then comes the manager who have some specific permissions i.e. manager doesn't have all the permissions as admin has.

Comment: Yes. So what? What is preventing you writing this logic for managers?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman i have a question that is there any specific words are there to define the manager , like a admin has is_superuser:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has_perm` method to check if the user has the specified permission. To redirect users based on their permissions, you can do something like this:

```
if user.has_perm('manager_permission'):
   return redirect('manager')
else:
   return redirect('index')
```

If you want to check for multiple permissions, you can use `has_perms` instead. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perms).

Comment: can you just explain me what is 'manager_permission' is doing here

Comment: The name of the permission that you've assigned to users. Just an example.

Comment: so in place of 'manager_permission' i have to write the permissions that i admin will provide

Comment: You said they have special permissions already? Anyway, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions

Comment: it's not working just take a look i have made changes in my code

Comment: Because you return before even checking the permission

Comment: if user.is_superuser:
            return redirect('manager') is this are you saying. but if user is a superuser then i want to render 'manager'  page and if user is manager i want to render 'master' page

Comment: when ever i enter that user who have special permission it is rendering only index page not the master page

Comment: The way you assign the permission to the user is incorrect. Please read again https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions

Comment: can you please tell me where i am lacking